# Will altering the robots.txt file require an iis restart?

Tags: iis, robots.txt

I am about to amend the robots txt file for a site, however I am curious if once the amendment is made I will need to restart iis for it fully take effect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The robots.txt is simply a text file retrievable through HTTP(S), as is any other file. It only instructs robots to behave in a certain way and has absolutely nothing to do with the behaviour of the webserver.
So: no restart required, IIS doesn't care about the contents.

Comment: Thanks @Florian. I can see the amendments internally but as of yet not replicated out externally as of yet. 
Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. if you have caches outside, their updates could of course take time, independent of your webserver. Also browser caches may be involved when checking.